# How to insert multiple values in a single excel cell and export it as a pdf for every entry of that cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i want to insert multiple values in a single cell and export every single entry as a separate pdf. The only thing i did till know is to manually reference the cells and export them as pdfs. This is my macro:

```
 Sub SavePDF()
     Range("A8").Value = Range("A8").Value + 1
        Sheet3.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="C:\Users\Report_" & _
            ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Value & ".pdf", _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End Sub
```

Lets say that i have a range: `M6:M14` and i want to input the results in the cell "M1". After i start the macro i want ot create for every single value **(the value should be inside the pdf)** a new pdf. Example: for the value of M6 a pdf, for M7 another and so on till i reach M14.

[image]

Comment: You are still not being clear; what do you mean by "insert" the values from `Range("M6:M14")` into `Range("M1")`, `Concatenate` `Sum`, `Add`? What do you mean by, "i want to export the first pdf where the first value of M1 is"? Please clarify and provide an example of what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code.

```
Sub SavePDF()

    Dim NameRange As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim PdfName As String

    Set NameRange = Range("M6:M14")

    For i = 1 To NameRange.Cells.Count
        PdfName = Trim(Range("A8").Value) & i
        With Sheet3
            .Range("M1").Value = NameRange.Cells(i).Value
            .ExportAsFixedFormat _
             Type:=xlTypePDF, _
             Filename:="C:\Users\Report_" & PdfName & ".pdf", _
             OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I did not explain myself properly. I want these values to be inside the pdf document. And for every different value from the range i want to make a new pdf. This code works perfectly but i get the values in the pdf name and not inside.

Comment: Your PDF is created from all of Sheet3. Anything you want to add to the PDF must go to Sheet3 first, before the PDF is created. In order to modify Sheet3 you should give the cell you want to  modify and the data you want to go to that cell. Now it seems that M6:M14 contains the data. But where in Sheet3 do you want them to go? Please revamp your question to include all this information.

Comment: I am sorry for my poor explanation . I want the range M6:M14 to the cell "M1". And after the first pdf is created, the second is automatically created with the second value and so on.. I've edited my post. Thank you!

Comment: @GMalc the thing is that i want the pdfs to have the content from M6:M14. The first value M6 should be inside the pdf. And for every single value from M6:M14 i want to create a different pdf.

Comment: @AngelVelkov still not too clear, but try modifying `Sheet3.ExportAsFixedFormat` to `Sheet3.Cells(i.Value).ExportAsFixedFormat`

Comment: @GMalc sorry, i will give another try. I have the range of values M6:M14. I want to create a macro where i insert the values from M6:M14 into the Cell M1. Afterwards i want to export the first pdf where the first value of M1 is, then a second pdf with the second value of M1 and so on.. Do you think that this is possible?

Comment: I have modified the above code and hope it'll now be nearer to the target. Observe that my code now assigns different names to the various PDFs each of which is different only in Sheet3!M1